# Find multiple indexes in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to find the indexes where a specific string is located in a multidimensional array in Ruby. I'm using the following code.

```
array = [['x', 'x',' x','x'],
         ['x', 'S',' ','x'],
         ['x', 'x','x','S']]

array.index(array.detect{|aa| aa.include?('S')}
```

However, this only returns 1 (the first index). Does anyone know how I can alter this command to return all the indexes where the pattern is present? This example should return 1 and 2.

Comment: A question "put on hold" has not be rejected. It simply means that you must edit the question to address the objection. If the edit is satisfactory the hold will be removed.

Comment: I nominate this question for re-opening. The edited question includes the input data, an approach that didn't work and the expected output. And frankly it already did when the last 2 close votes came in...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the updated solution now that you updated your question and added the below comment:

```
array.each_index.select { |i| array[i].include?('S') }
#=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original because I realised that the array and subarray indexes were the same, which may be causing some confusion. So, what I want are the indexes of the subarrays containing the string. I'm not concerned with the location within each subarray. However, I get the same response when I use both your solutions, which is [nil, 1, 3]. What I"m looking for is 1,2. Hopefully that clears things up a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @kms Updated, this now does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
array = [['x', 'x',' x','x'],
         ['x', 'S',' ','x'],
         ['x', 'x','x','S']]

array.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(row,i),arr|
  j = row.index('S')
  arr << i unless j.nil?
end
  #=> [1, 2]
```

It's only a small change to retrieve both the row and column indices (assuming there is at most one target string per row):

```
array.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(row,i),arr|
  j = row.index('S')
  arr << [i,j] unless j.nil?
end
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

You can also use the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class to obtain row/column pairs.

```
require 'matrix'

Matrix[*array].each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,i,j),arr| arr << [i,j] if e == 'S' }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Don't you think that `each.with_index.with_object([])` has a nice symmetry (i.e. just chaining all the `Enumerable` methods)? :)

Comment: @MichaelKohl, yes, though you don't show any so far... :-)

Comment: Ugh, I wrote `Enumerable` again when I meant `Enumerator`. One day I'll get this right... ;)